# why there is a difference in the result of addition in mathamatica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Iam trying to solve 32 linear coupled differential equations where, when i add them before solving, they should get cancel and result should be exactly zero because the coefficients are so. But it is showing a non zero value in 10^-6 which i don't want. As it can be seen in the following program. When i add all the 'A' and 'W' values (coefficients) they are zero, but when i add them together it is giving a non zero value. please can some one help ?? (ROSE & LILLY are zero individually but why the LOTUS is not zero ?)

```
A1 = 507762.5`;
A2 = 126940.625`;

A3 = 18134.375`;
A4 = 1.468884375`*^6;

A5 =  489628.125`;
A = -2.61135`*^6;

W1 = -571967.7214761395`;
W2 = -190655.90715871312`;

W3 = 571967.7214761395`;
W4 = 190655.90715871312`;

ROSE = A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 + A;

LILLY = W1 + W2 + W3 + W4;

JASMINE = ROSE + LILLY

LOTUS = A1 + W1 + A2 + W2 + A3 + W3 + A4 + W4 + A5 + A
```

Answer (score 1):

The inconsistency in your answer appears due to the default precision Mathematica sets. The rule of thumb is that the larger is the length of the digits after the decimal, the more precision you need. For example, in your code `W3` needs higher precision to retain all the decimal parts that you mentioned than the variable `A1`.

However, I believe that Mathematica maintains a standard precision for all the calculations unless you specify it. You can specify the precision to an arbitrary value in Mathematica by the command `SetPrecision`. If you now specify a precision, say 50, to all the variables, then the inconsistency disappears. Hope this helps!

Comment: good explanation, however depending on what the actual problem is the remedy may be to simply recognize this as a normal feature of floating point arithmetic ie. 10^-10 is effectively zero.  Working at extended precision may seriously degrade performance so you shouldn't do it unless really needed.